# what setup method for Moq do in unit test with dependency injection in dot net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, .net-core, moq

I have dot net core website , based on dependency injection ,the controller is.

```
public class TokenController : Controller
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IUserService _iuserService;

    public TokenController(IConfiguration config, IUserService iUserService)
    {
        _config = config;
        _iuserService = iUserService;
    }
     public UserViewModel Authenticate(LoginModel login)
    {
        UserViewModel user = null;
        user = this._iuserService.Login(login.Username, login.Password);
        return user;
    }

  }
```

and i want to do unit test for Authenticate method ,the unit test class is ,

```
 [TestClass]
 public class TokenUnitTest
 {
    private IUserService _IUserService;
    private IConfiguration _config;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var mockIUserService = new Mock<IUserService>();
        UserViewModel returnedobj = new UserViewModel();
        returnedobj.Email = "sam@sam.com";
        returnedobj.Name = "sam";
        mockIUserService.Setup(x => x.Login("sam", "123")).Returns(returnedobj);
        _IUserService = mockIUserService.Object;

        var _configurationRoot = new Mock<IConfigurationRoot>();
        _configurationRoot.SetupGet(x => x[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns("Key");
        this._config = _configurationRoot.Object;
    }
  [TestMethod]
    public void Authenticate()
    {
        ////arrange

        LoginModel _LoginModel = new LoginModel("sam", "123");
        var config = InitConfiguration();
        var clientId = config["CLIENT_ID"];
        TokenController _TokenController = new TokenController(config, _IUserService);
        ////act
        UserViewModel LoginnedUser = _TokenController.Authenticate(_LoginModel);

        ////assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(LoginnedUser);
    }
}
```

The problem is when i put break point at authenticate method it return the returnd data that exist in setupMock. Why it doesn't go to database and return the true data.
the second problem is the breakpoint doesn't enter in UserService ,it deal with interface ,, why dependency injection doesn't work ??

Comment: I think, mockIUserService should be declared in class scope not in setup function. And mockIUserService.Object should be  passed to the constructor of controller.

Comment: The whole point of unit testing is not having to deal with a database. You are correctly mocking IUserService which means no instance of UserService is ever created. This is okay as you are testing the controller and not the service: i.e. a valid or invalid login

Comment: How is that ??!! But what if i want to test the whole cycle and ensure that the data returned correctly ??

Comment: @HodaOsama in that case no mocking is needed and you can simply pass a real instance of IUserService: `new UserService()`. This is no longer a unit test but an integration test though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an integration test no mocking is required:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    _IUserService = new UserService(); // create a real instance
}
```

Comment: But i have many dependencies,it will be

      TokenController _TokenController = new TokenController(config, new 
      UserService(new UserRepository(new ContractManagementContext())));
It is Best Practise??

Comment: Of course, if you wish to test against a database, you will need to setup the context for that

Comment: i need to setup the context and insert virtual data in it to be able to test on this virtual data. So there is no way to test on data that exist already on database .

Comment: It should work if you use the username and password of an existing user in the `LoginModel` that is passed into the `Authenticate` method. Note that this is not ideal security-wise (password of existing user in plain text) and fragile (password could change). Ideally you would create a dummy user in the `Setup()` method via an API that allows you to add a user to the database and clean it up afterwards in a cleanup method `[TestCleanup]` using that same API